# How to call a class that extends Fragment from a Service class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I tried with fragment transaction, but didn't get that in a class extending service.kindly help me out with this.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Not clear what you want..

Comment: I have a "Listview" in a seperate class that extends Fragment. I need to call this class from another class which extends Service. Basically, we use fragment transaction to call a Fragment from Activity..But here, I've to call Fragment from Service Class.

Comment: A service has no UI. A fragment is a UI element. What you're trying to do makes no sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to my understanding you have to use bind service .so you can communicate with ibinder service object.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html